# Python write GPIO values

Tags: python

I am a complete noob using a Raspberry Pi trying to make a program that would track instances of movement with a PIR sensor set on GPIO 4, now the program works without any issues until I try to export the data, long story short, I try gspread, and ubidots and both won't work, even just with a test file. So my next attempt is a simple txt file that will capture time and date, and would write a 1.

this is what I have:

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sensor = 4


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

prevstate = False
currState = False

while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        prevState = currState
        currState = GPIO.input(sensor)
        if currState != prevState:
                newState = "1" if currState else "0"
                print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, newState))

                try:
                    values  = [datetime.datetime.now(), newState]
                    with open("test.txt", "a") as text_file:
                        text_file.write("values")

time.sleep(1.5)
```

So i don't really don't now why but everything works until I hit the value section, and then I get a unindent error, if I remove from try down i get nothing

I did had before:

```
except: 
    print: "cannot open file"
```

but that really wasn't any issue there. the unindent still comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You have indentation issues.  It looks like you started allowing Idle to tab - 8 for indentation then switched to 4.  You need to unindent and re-indent everything.

The way you are handling your file, you will overwrite it every time through.  You will end up with only one entry in the file.  Try opening the file before your main loop:

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

prevstate = False
currState = False

with open("test.txt", "a") as text_file:  
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        prevState = currState
        currState = GPIO.input(sensor)
        if currState != prevState:
            newState = "1" if currState else "0"
            print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, newState))

            try:
                values  = [datetime.datetime.now(), newState]
                text_file.write("values")
            except: 
                print "cannot open file"
```

get rid of the colon ":" after print, and that sleep after your main loop was not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You must always follow the try statement with an except or finally statement, but you mentioned that you also got the error with the try statement? Did that also include the : after print (it shouldn't)? This should work:

```
            try:
                values  = [datetime.datetime.now(), newState]
                with open("test.txt", "a") as text_file:
                    text_file.write(values)
            except: 
                print: "cannot open file"
```

Notice that I also removed the quotes around values in text_file.write(values).

Comment: well that really didn't do much: adding the except statment just brought a syntax error on that line that says inconsistent use of tabs and indentations:
        `try:
               values  = [datetime.datetime.now(), newState]
               with open("test.txt", "a") as text_file:
                   text_file.write(values)
        except:
     print: "cannot open file"
time.sleep(1.5)`

Comment: Remove all tabs and spaces before the lines and indent it so it looks identical as above, it is due mixture of tabs vs ordinary spaces for indentation.

Comment: this code will work now, as in you get all the appropiate responses`try:
            values = "[datetime.datetime.now(), new_state]"
            with open("test.txt", "a") as text_file:
                text_file.write(values), the only problem It would only write [datetime.datetime.now(), new_state] so not import from datetime is happening...any ideas?